# Ajax update existing messages

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, chat

Im building a chat system prototype, and i have a problem.
I cannot copy the messages, because it disappers for like 10-20ms and it marks all the messages.

```
var RefreshTimerInterval = 100; // << ...MS
$(document).ready(getData)

function getData() {
$.get('table_data.php', function(result) {
 $('#table_data').html(result);
 if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)
 }
 setTimeout(getData, RefreshTimerInterval);
})
}
```

```
<?php
include 'dbConfig.php';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pmsg ORDER BY send_on";
    $result = $db->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            ?>
            <h4 style="margin-top:0px"><?php echo $row['author'].': '.'<span style="font-weight:300">'.$row['message'].'</span>' ?></h4>
            <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I assume you mean you can't select all the messages in order to cut-and-paste.  That's true, because you're refreshing the control 10 times a second.  You need to come up with a more sophisticated algorithm that only sends over what is NEW, and leaves the old content alone.  Also, you might consider just sending over a JSON with the messages, and leave the HTML formatting to the Javascipt.

Comment: So, its better to send a JSON with the message to the database?

Comment: Well, THIS code is about the display side, not the "new message" side.  I'm suggesting that the Javascript could send over an index or timestamp of the last message it got, your PHP code could just send over the messages that are new since then, and your Javascript could format and add them to the display.